# Cannot implicitly convert type System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<> to bool

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm developing an ASP.NET MVC 4 Application and I'm trying to run this Lambda expression in Entity Framework 5.

```
var customer = db.GNL_Customer.Where(d => d.GNL_City.FKProvinceID == advancedProvinceID || advancedProvinceID == null)
            .Where(d => d.FKCityID == advancedCityID || advancedCityID == null)
            .Where(d => d.FKDepartmentStoreID == advancedDepartmentStoreID || advancedDepartmentStoreID == null)
            .Where(d => d.GNL_CustomerLaptopProduct.Where(r => String.Compare(r.BrandName, brandID) == 0 || brandID == null));
```

I get this error :

`Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<ITKaranDomain.GNL_CustomerLaptopProduct>' to 'bool'`

I know that the last where clause is wrong but I don't know how to correct it.

Comment: As Andrew pointed out in his answer, you need to use `Any` as `Where will return an `IEnumerable<T>` and the predicate for `Any` needs a `bool` returning function.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You might want another `.Any` instead of a `.Where` in your `.Any` clause at the end:

```
var customer = db.GNL_Customer.Where(d => d.GNL_City.FKProvinceID == advancedProvinceID || advancedProvinceID == null)
            .Where(d => d.FKCityID == advancedCityID || advancedCityID == null)
            .Where(d => d.FKDepartmentStoreID == advancedDepartmentStoreID || advancedDepartmentStoreID == null)
            .Any(d => d.GNL_CustomerLaptopProduct.Any(r => String.Compare(r.BrandName, brandID) == 0 || brandID == null));
```

Answer (score 6):

Use `Where ( Any )` in last statement to select customers which have at least one product satisfying your conditions:

```
var customer = db.GNL_Customer
   .Where(d => d.GNL_City.FKProvinceID == advancedProvinceID || advancedProvinceID == null)
   .Where(d => d.FKCityID == advancedCityID || advancedCityID == null)
   .Where(d => d.FKDepartmentStoreID == advancedDepartmentStoreID || advancedDepartmentStoreID == null)
   .Where(d => brandID == null || d.GNL_CustomerLaptopProduct.Any(r => r.BrandName == brandID));
```