# Consult records within the master detail from the master table Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I need to consult records within the master detail from the master table. I have the `purchases` table and the `purchases detail` table, and I need to consult the purchases that contain the product collection.

Model params:

```
public class PurchaseParmsDto
{       
    public ICollection<Int32> ProductsId { get; set; }
}
```

Query:

```
var query = (from p in _context.Purchase
             where p.DetailPurchase.Where(x => purchaseParms.ProductsId.Contains(x.IdProducto))
             select new...)
```

I get this error when running the query:

> Severity Code Description Project File Line Status deleted
>   Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' en 'bool'
>   ApplicationComercio   D:\Proyectos\AppComercioMultiApi\ApplicationComercio\Controllers\PurchasesController.cs 163 Activo

Could you help me please? Thanks

Comment: can you post your complete query ? its hard to see what you are trying to achieve with that

Comment: also have a look here if this can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14627196/cannot-implicitly-convert-type-system-collections-generic-ienumerable-to-bool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**replace any where.**

This query allows you to search within the details of the master table, all the matching products

```
var query = (
                    from p in _context.Purchase
                    where p.DetailPurchase.Any(x => purchaseParms.Products.Count==0|| purchaseParms.Products.Contains(x.IdProducto))
```